# How to get current index of element in polars list

Tags: python, python-polars

When evaluating list elements I would like to know and use the current index. Is there already a way of doing it?

Something like `pl.element().idx()` ?

```
import polars as pl

data = {"a": [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}
schema = {"a": pl.List(pl.Int8)}

df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema=schema).with_columns([
    pl.col("a").list.eval(pl.element() * pl.element().idx() )
])
```

Expected result:

```
+-------------+
¦ a           ¦
¦ ---         ¦
¦ list[u8]    ¦
¦-------------¦
¦ [0, 2, 6]   ¦
¦ [0, 5, 12]  ¦
+-------------+
```

Comment: This feels like the x, y problem. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way (that I know of) is to make a row index, explode, use cumcount with a window function to create the idx (I'm calling it j), and then put it back together with groupby/agg

```
(
    df
        .with_row_count('i')
        .explode('a')
        .with_columns(j=pl.first().cumcount().over('i'))
        .with_columns(new=pl.col('a')*pl.col('j'))
        .groupby('i', maintain_order=True)
        .agg(pl.col('new'))
        .drop('i')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `apply` method along with the `enumerate` function to achieve the desired result of accessing the current index of each element in a list column. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
import polars as pl

data = {"a": [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}
schema = {"a": pl.List(pl.Int8)}

df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema=schema).with_columns([
    pl.col("a").apply(lambda arr: [x * i for i, x in enumerate(arr)])
])

print(df)
```

Output

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ a          │
│ ---        │
│ list[i64]  │
╞════════════╡
│ [0, 2, 6]  │
│ [0, 5, 12] │
└────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like to avoid apply. When working with large data sets, apply is to slow.

Answer (score 1):

The index of an element within a list can easily be accessed using [`pl.element().cum_count()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cum_count.html) as follows:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("a").list.eval(pl.element() * pl.element().cum_count())
)
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ a          │
│ ---        │
│ list[i64]  │
╞════════════╡
│ [0, 2, 6]  │
│ [0, 5, 12] │
└────────────┘
```