# divide every nth element of a list with a number in polars DataFrame column of lists

Tags: list, transformation, python-polars

I have the following DataFrame

```
import polars as pl

data = {
    'col': [[11, 21, 31, 41, 51], [12, 22, 32, 42, 52], [13, 23, 33, 43, 53]]
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────────┐
│ col            │
│ ---            │
│ list[i64]      │
╞════════════════╡
│ [11, 21, … 51] │
│ [12, 22, … 52] │
│ [13, 23, … 53] │
└────────────────┘
```

Starting from the first element of each list, I want to divide every two elements of the list with a number, and then starting from the second element of the list, divide again every two elements with another number. For example, if these two numbers are 5 and 10 respectively, the first list will be transformed like this

```
[11/5, 21/10, 31/5, 41/10, 51/5]
```

resulting in

```
[2.2, 2.1, 6.2, 4.1, 10.2]
```

I want to do the same transformation for all the lists of the column. How can I do that using the polars API?

Comment: The first list in the code is `[11, 21, 31, 41, 51]` but the description uses `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]` which makes it somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Will the lists always be of the same length?

Comment: @jqurious you are right, I edited the post.

Comment: @Hericks the lists do not have the same length, but their lengths are always even numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list.eval` and when/then/otherwise

```py
import polars as pl

data = {"col": [[11, 21, 31, 41, 51], [12, 22, 32, 42, 52], [13, 23, 33, 43, 53]]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)


def func(x):
    return pl.when(x.cum_count() % 2 == 0).then(x / 5).otherwise(x / 10)


df.select(result=pl.col("col").list.eval(func(pl.element())))
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────────────┐
│ result             │
│ ---                │
│ list[f64]          │
╞════════════════════╡
│ [2.2, 2.1, … 10.2] │
│ [2.4, 2.2, … 10.4] │
│ [2.6, 2.3, … 10.6] │
└────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Nice use of `pl.Expr.cum_count()`. I've posted a corresponding answer to a questions explicitly asking about accessing list element indices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76523245/how-to-get-current-index-of-element-in-polars-list/77751528#77751528).

Comment: @ignoring_gravity very nice solution. Since I am new to polars library, I want to ask what is the difference of your solution instead of using `Expr.map_elements`. In both cases I define a function, this is why I am asking. The polars documentation of `map_elements` says to only use it when there is no other way to implement your logic because it is too slow. This is why I asked for the polars API in OP.

Comment: map_elements applies a custom Python function to each element, and is slow. but the solution I posted uses the polars API and so should be way faster